# Follow random person on Twitter (Tweepy)?

Tags: python, tweepy

I've been looking on the internet for a way to follow a random user on Twitter in a while loop. While I've seen the loop you can use to find tweets (and then do something), how do you find users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy library has an API `search_users(q)` to retrieve the first 1000 matches based on the query `'q'`.

[API Documentation](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.search_users)